# Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

Tags: .net, webrequest

I just got this exception (ProtocolViolationException) in my .NET 2.0 app (running on windows mobile 6 standard emulator).  What confuses me is that as far as i know, I have not added any content body, unless I've inadvertently done it somehow.  My code is below (very simple).  Is there anything else i need to do to convince .NET that this is just a http GET?

```
//run get and grab response
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(get.AbsoluteUri + args);
request.Method = "GET";
Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();           // <= explodes here
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
```

Comment: Solution found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72179255/restsharp-error-cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Don't get the request stream, quite simply. GET requests don't *usually* have bodies (even though it's [not technically prohibited by HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064281/sending-post-data-with-get-request-valid)) and `WebRequest` doesn't support it - but that's what calling `GetRequestStream` is for, providing body data for the request.

Given that you're trying to *read* from the stream, it looks to me like you actually want to get the *response* and read the response stream from that:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(get.AbsoluteUri + args);
request.Method = "GET";
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Technically, GET requests can have bodies, but .NET does not support generating GET reqeusts with bodies. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064281/sending-post-data-with-get-request-valid

Comment: @JonSkeet You must be a genius or something. That's exactly what solved my problem. +1.

Comment: @EternalLearner You have that backwards. The proper expression is, "Genius, you must be a Skeet or something." :)  This sorted me out too, and I gave the responder a +1 before I realized I was helping Mr. Skeet to 1M.

Comment: @JonSkeet, is there a way to send a GET request with a content body using `HttpClient` and `HttpRequestMessage`?

Comment: @JonSkeet NM I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11091160/rest-api-get-request-with-body).

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar issue using Flurl.Http:

`Flurl.Http.FlurlHttpException: Call failed. Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type. GET http://******:8301/api/v1/agents/**** ---> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`

The problem was I used `.WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")` when creating IFlurlRequest.

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't specify the Header.

I've added an extended example:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strServer + strURL.Split('&')[1].ToString());
```

**Header(ref request, p_Method);**

And the method Header:

```
private void Header(ref HttpWebRequest p_request, string p_Method)
{
    p_request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    p_request.Method = p_Method;
    p_request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows CE)";
    p_request.Host = strServer.Split('/')[2].ToString();
    p_request.Accept = "*/*";
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(strURLReferer))
    {
        p_request.Referer = strServer;
    }
    else
    {
        p_request.Referer = strURLReferer;
    }
    p_request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us\r\n");
    p_request.Headers.Add("UA-CPU", "x86 \r\n");
    p_request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache\r\n");
    p_request.KeepAlive = true;
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Please set the request Content Type before you read the response stream;

```
 request.ContentType = "text/xml";
```