# How to use HttpClient to send content in body of GET request?

Tags: c#, get, request, dotnet-httpclient

Currently to send a parameterized GET request to an API interface I am writing the following code:

```
api/master/city/filter?cityid=1&citycode='ny'
```

But I see that there is a limit on the URL length of 2,083 characters.

To avoid this I would like to send the parameters in json format in the content body for a GET request.

However, I see that none of the Get methods for the HttpClient allow for a content body to be sent. For the POST I could see there is a method within HttpClient named PostAsync that allows for a content body.

Is there a way to send parameters for a GET request not in the URL in order to avoid the URL length limit?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

So basically, even though you might be able to do this in theory, you really shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: you can't send a body with a GET request, not with HttpClient or WebClient or anything else. but even if you manage to do it at low level, the server won't parse the body anyways because it will treat it as a GET request.

Comment: The reason you can't is because by definition, GET is meant to retrieve a resource. It's not likely that anyone will need that many characters to retrieve a resource. It's more likely that you're intending to submit data instead of rerieve it, which is what POST is designed for. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: Could be GET eg getbyWhere? id=&id=....  but It hits the 4K limit making it a post is not nice either.

Comment: @SelmanGenç Wrong, see my answer.

Answer (score 117):

Please read the caveats at the end of this answer as to why HTTP GET requests with bodies are, in general, not advised.

---

- If you are using .NET **Core**, the standard [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient) can do this out-of-the-box. For example, to send a GET request with a JSON body:

  ```
  HttpClient client = ...

  ...

  var request = new HttpRequestMessage
  {
      Method = HttpMethod.Get,
      RequestUri = new Uri("some url"),
      Content = new StringContent(
          "some json",
          Encoding.UTF8,
          MediaTypeNames.Application.Json), // or "application/json" in older versions
  };

  var response = await client.SendAsync(request)
      .ConfigureAwait(false);
  response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

  var responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
      .ConfigureAwait(false);
  ```
- .NET **Framework** doesn't support this out-of-the-box (you will receive a `ProtocolViolationException` if you try the above code). Thankfully Microsoft has provided the [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/) package that *does* support the functionality - simply install and use it instead of the default [`HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler) when constructing your `HttpClient` instances:

  ```
  var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
  var client = new HttpClient(handler);

  <rest of code as above>
  ```

  Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25485#issuecomment-467261945

---

Caveats:

- HTTP GET with a body is a somewhat unconventional construct that falls in a gray area of the HTTP specification - the end result is that many older pieces of software either cannot handle such a request at all, or will explicitly reject it because they believe it to be malformed. You need to make very sure that the endpoint you're trying to send such a request to does support it, or at best you will get an HTTP error code back; at worst the body will be silently discarded. This can lead to some head-scratching debugging!
- Caching proxy servers, again particularly older ones, may cache GET requests based only on the URL because they don't expect a body to be present. This could either result in the least recent request being cached forever (which will break your software), or that the only request ever cached is the most recent one issued (which will prevent caching from working as intended). Again, this can be very painful to figure out.

Comment: This raises **ProtocolViolationException**.

Comment: @Alisson Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: Hi Ian! No, I'm using .NET 4.7, does this work only with .NET Core? Thank you!

Comment: In .Net 4.7.2, I kept getting an error with `ContentType.Json`, so I had to use `"application/json"`.

Answer (score 36):

I can't use .NET core and I don't  want to install `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler`, which has a ton of dependencies.
I solved it by using reflection, to trick `WebRequest` that it is legal to send body with a GET request (which is according to latest RFC). What I do is to set `ContentBodyNotAllowed` to false for HTTP verb "GET".

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "GET";

var type = request.GetType();
var currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(request);

var methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write("<Json string here>");
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Note, however, that the attribute `ContentBodyNotAllowed` belongs to a static field, so when its value changes, it remains in effect for the rest of the program. That's not a problem for my purposes.

Comment: life saver! thx so much for this solution. worked perfect!!

Comment: A nifty workaround! Just be aware that since this uses reflection, there's no guarantee it will continue to work (e.g. if Microsoft renames `ContentBodyNotAllowed`).

Comment: Were you, by any chance, able to mock this, so as to cover it in a unit test?

Comment: @justinb I haven't used it in a unit test

Answer (score 2):

I use WebRequest.
The value is in variable json.

```
            var request = WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + Token);

            var type = request.GetType();
            var currentMethod = type.GetProperty("CurrentMethod", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(request);

            var methodType = currentMethod.GetType();
            methodType.GetField("ContentBodyNotAllowed", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(currentMethod, false);

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Entity));
            }

            var response = request.GetResponse();
            var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                var myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
                var resultEntity= myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                myStreamReader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            responseStream.Close();
            response.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

After spending a lot of time I couldn't make neither `HttpClient` nor `WebRequest` work in my .Net Core project, apparently the server was not getting my data and it returned an error saying some specific data was not available in my request. At last only `RestSharp` worked in my case (the variable `myData` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` instance in the following code):

```
var client = new RestClient("some url");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
foreach (var d in myData)
    request.AddParameter(d.Key, d.Value);
var result = (await client.ExecuteAsync(request)).Content;
```

Answer (score -2):

similar to above answer but less code

```cs
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = targetUri,
    Content = new StringContent(payload.Payload),
};
var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
var responseInfo = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```