# Mollie payment `Unauthorized Request` while hit the URL using C# but it's working on postman

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mollie

Mollie Payment fail while sending request in `https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments`

using `HttpClient` class in `System.Net.Http`

Mollie payment request using `v2/payments` API working fine  through `Postman` but getting `unauthorized` request error in `c#` code

> below code

```
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

public HttpRequestMessage CreateHttpRequest(HttpMethod method, string relativeUri, HttpContent content = null)
{
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(method, new Uri(new Uri(ApiEndPoint), relativeUri));
    httpRequest.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    httpRequest.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this._apiKey);
    httpRequest.Content = content;

    return httpRequest;
}

public HttpResponseMessage SendHttpRequestAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, string relativeUri, object data = null)
{
    HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = this.CreateHttpRequest(httpMethod, relativeUri);
    if (data != null)
    {       
        var content = new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        httpRequest.Content = content;
    }

    HttpResponseMessage response = _httpClient.GetAsync(httpRequest.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri).Result;
    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        //here main logic
    }

    return response;
}
```

> Message from received by Mollie server
>   [image: Mollie message]

```
{
  "Version": {
    "Major": 1,
    "Minor": 1,
    "Build": -1,
    "Revision": -1,
    "MajorRevision": -1,
    "MinorRevision": -1
  },
  "Content": {
    "Headers": [
      {
        "Key": "Content-Length",
        "Value": [
          "209"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Key": "Content-Type",
        "Value": [
          "application/hal+json"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "StatusCode": 401,
  "ReasonPhrase": "Unauthorized Request",
  "Headers": [
    {
      "Key": "X-Content-Type-Options",
      "Value": [
        "nosniff"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Strict-Transport-Security",
      "Value": [
        "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Date",
      "Value": [
        "Tue, 21 Jan 2020 06:11:41 GMT"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "Server",
      "Value": [
        "nginx"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Key": "WWW-Authenticate",
      "Value": [
        "Basic realm=\"Mollie API Key\""
      ]
    }
  ],
  "RequestMessage": {
    "Version": {
      "Major": 1,
      "Minor": 1,
      "Build": -1,
      "Revision": -1,
      "MajorRevision": -1,
      "MinorRevision": -1
    },
    "Content": null,
    "Method": {
      "Method": "GET"
    },
    "RequestUri": "https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments",
    "Headers": [],
    "Properties": {}
  },
  "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
}
```

> But main issues is Test_api working in postman when hit the URL

[image: Postman image]

Comment: Try setting the authorization header for the `_httpclient`: `_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this._apiKey);`

Comment: thank you, I have done the same but now working can you shared something else?

Comment: Yes now it's working, I have done the same can you share something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work :

```
using(var httpClient = new HttpClient()) {
 httpClient.SetBearerToken(tokenValue);
 var serData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(modelData);
 var httpRequestContentData = new StringContent(serData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
 using(var result = httpClient.PostAsync(url, httpRequestContentData).Result) {
  if ((int) result.StatusCode == (int) HttpStatusCode.OK) {
   // Go Ahead 
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Nikunj but received this message using above code
`StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 08:53:12 GMT
  Server: nginx
  WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Mollie API Key"
  Content-Length: 209
  Content-Type: application/hal+json
`

Comment: If I'm adding token in the header this message received.
`StatusCode: 422, ReasonPhrase: 'Unprocessable Entity', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
  Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 09:00:17 GMT
  Server: nginx
  Content-Length: 213
  Content-Type: application/hal+json
}`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your case, you should add the `Bearer` on the header for the `_httpclient`:

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", this._apiKey);
```

Now, since you are sending a request body to a `GET` request which is somewhat unconventional construct that falls in a gray area of the HTTP specification - the end result is that many older pieces of software either cannot handle such a request at all, or will explicitly reject it because they believe it to be malformed.

.NET Framework doesn't support this out-of-the-box (you will receive a `ProtocolViolationException`). You can install `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler` and use it instead of the default `HttpClientHandler` when constructing your client:

```
var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
//Same code as in question
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working now but the main this how to send request objects as well as?

Comment: If I'm using `SendAsync` getting the error `ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.
`

Comment: @jishansiddique What do you get when you do: `_httpClient.GetAsync(httpRequest.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri).Result;`

Comment: I'm getting `200 status code`  if I'm calling this `_httpClient.GetAsync` there is no way to send `Request object` so how we can map if I'm going with `SendAsync` getting `verb-type` error.

Comment: @jishansiddique Can you show me your `payments` API? I guess you are getting confused with the `GET` and `POST` request. You probably need a POST request in your case but I need to see how you have designed your API. The HTTP 200 OK success status response code indicates that the request has succeeded. What do you get in your `response` object on a `200` ?

Comment: No Mollie payment gateway accept only get request 
`https://api.mollie.com/v2/payments`

Comment: @jishansiddique What do you get in your response object on the `200` call ?

Comment: Yes I'm getting 200 but the problem is how to pass request object in `_httpClient`

Comment: @jishansiddique More on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421126/possible-for-httpclient-to-send-content-or-body-for-get-request/47902348

Comment: @jishansiddique If this answers your question, please consider marking it as the accepted answer and don't forget to up-vote.:)

Comment: Yes I know that but issues are not resolved I'm trying another approach

Comment: `WinHttpHandler` we can't install this because we are working product so that it's not allowed.

Comment: @jishansiddique See the last answer from the link in the comment

Comment: Yes I'm referring this link.

Comment: Not working bro thank you for your support and quick connected.

Comment: @jishansiddique If my answer helped you out, you can accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Calling `_httpClient.GetAsync(Uri)` creates a brand-new `HttpRequestMessage` object internally, instead of using your object configured with an `Authorization:` header.

Use `_httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest)` instead to actually use your object.

Comment: Thanks for reply but getting error `ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`