# Rest GET request in C# with body

Tags: c#, rest, elasticsearch

I am trying to make a GET request with a body to a REST API - without success.
The API sits on top of Elastisearch, which requires a body for requests.
The body contains the filters and requests for specific fields for the request.
I have tried multiple different requests in Postman and they work fine. The body is forwarded and the results are filtered as expected.

The API is state run which means i have no control over it what so ever. 
It refuses any request that is not GET (POST, PUT etc.).

I have tried with RestSharp, but it refuses to make a GET request with a body.
Error message is: "Http verb GET does not support body".
(i tried to get the C# code from Postman, but it throws the same exception).

I have also tried with HttpClient, HttpWebRequest and WebClient. Same error in all of them.
To try a new platform i created a PowerShell script to run from C#, but it throws the same exception.

Is this just impossible to do in C#?

My only option now is to create e.g. a PHP (or other language) script that can query the API succefully, and then access this script from C#. But it seems like quite a workaround only because of the GET/body problem.

Any advice or ressources you could provide or refer me to would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Btw. i have seen a lot of posts on Stackoverflow on this problem. Many of them are quite old so i am hoping that perhaps something has changed. Also many of them end up with a solution where you use POST instead of GET - which is not a option for me.

Comment: There is .Net client called Nest for elasticsearch. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/elasticsearch-net-getting-started.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Comment: Also seems relevant, found shortly after vtc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902348/313414 suggests a workaround to make HttpClient do what you're asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NEST (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/nest.html) - client for elastic for .net

Example code:

```
var elasticUrls =  new Uri[]{new Uri("http://localhost:9200") };
            var connect = new ConnectionSettings(
                    new SniffingConnectionPool(elasticUrls, true, null),
                    (builtin, settings) =>
                        new JsonNetSerializer(
                            builtin,
                            settings,
                            null,
                            null,
                            new JsonConverter[] {new StringEnumConverter()})
                );

var client = new ElasticClient(connect);

var searchResult = await client.SearchAsync<ElasticModel>(
                d => d
                    .Query(q => q.Bool(qd => qd
                        .Must(m => m.MatchAll())
                    ))
                    .From(0)
                    .Size(10)
            ).ConfigureAwait(false);

    /// <summary>
    /// Some model from Elastic
    /// </summary>
    class ElasticModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using RestSharp, in the `request.AddParameter` use `ParameterType.GetOrPost` instead of `ParameterType.RequestBody`

```
request.AddParameter("application/json", "things", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
```

Comment: The latest version of RestSharp (106) is giving error message -  "HTTP verb does not support body"