# Business Central Get Token SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, postman, dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I'm trying to connect the business central with the sharepoint, I already did it in the postman, it worked fine, the GET and POST.
But now Im trying to do it on BC, the token is created but not working, I think it has some problem with the connection or the URL's.

```
codeunit 50100 "APISharePoint"
{

    var
        OAuth2: Codeunit OAuth2;
        ClientIdTxt: Label '4d148348-137a-40e7-b20c-a458c2a03c65', Locked = true;
        ClientSecret: Label 'Ai2pOhE7yeZ8WRxrwSrHdpVtNqJg51tg2X+s8CJDLy4=', Locked = true;
        ResourceUrlTxt: Label 'https://crmbc384959.sharepoint.com', Locked = true;
        OAuthAuthorityUrlTxt: Label 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/ec36749a-af47-4f04-892c-98666b6cac1b/oauth2/v2.0/token', Locked = true;


    procedure GetAccessToken(): Text
    var
        PromptInteraction: Enum "Prompt Interaction";
        AccessToken: Text;
        AuthCodeError: Text;
        RedirectURLTxt: Text;
    begin
        // OAuth2.GetDefaultRedirectURL(RedirectURLTxt);
        RedirectURLTxt := 'https://localhost';
        if OAuth2.AcquireTokenWithClientCredentials(ClientIdTxt, ClientSecret, OAuthAuthorityUrlTxt, RedirectURLTxt, ResourceURLTxt, AccessToken) then
            exit(AccessToken)
        else
            exit('');
    end;


    procedure HttpGet(AccessToken: Text; Url: Text /*var JResponse: JsonObject*/): Boolean
    var
        Client: HttpClient;
        Headers: HttpHeaders;
        RequestMessage: HttpRequestMessage;
        ResponseMessage: HttpResponseMessage;
        RequestContent: HttpContent;
        ResponseText: Text;
        IsSucces: Boolean;

    begin
        Headers := Client.DefaultRequestHeaders();
        Headers.Add('Authorization', StrSubstNo('Bearer %1', AccessToken));
        Headers.Add('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        RequestMessage.Content.GetHeaders(Headers); //asd
        Headers.Remove('Content-Type');
        Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/json;odata=verbose');
        RequestMessage.SetRequestUri(Url);
        RequestMessage.Method := 'GET';

        if Client.Send(RequestMessage, ResponseMessage) then
            if ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode() then begin
                if ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAs(ResponseText) then
                    IsSucces := true;
                //     end else
                //         ResponseMessage.Content.ReadAs(ResponseText);

                // JResponse.ReadFrom(ResponseText);
                exit(IsSucces);

            end;

    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem is the combination of GET with a request content.
As far as i know, the underlaying implementation of the HttpClient in .NET does not support GET with a request content. You can read more about it here: [How to use HttpClient to send content in body of GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421126/how-to-use-httpclient-to-send-content-in-body-of-get-request)

Maybe you can try GET without setting the content-type on the content or use POST or PUT instead.

But you didn't supply a error message so this is just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly too late and you've already found a solution, I hope :).
if not, some SharePoint scopes don't accept the use of an App Registration with only the client and secret (this is the case for Project Online).
You need a token request via an SSL certificate.
The procedure for creating and setting up the certificate is here:
https://anupamchand.medium.com/azure-active-directory-authentication-using-client-certificates-4274932a5061
The following code will give you a token that will work:

procedure AcquireTokenOAuth2(var AuthError: text) AccessToken: Text
var
Client: HttpClient;
RequestMessage: HttpRequestMessage;
Content: HttpContent;
Headers: HttpHeaders;
ResponseMessage: HttpResponseMessage;
Uri: Text;
RequestBody: Text;
ResponseBody: Text;
OAuthClientId: text;
OAuthClientSecret: Text;
Json: JsonObject;
begin
Uri := 'https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/v2.0/token';
RequestMessage.Method('POST');
RequestMessage.SetRequestUri(Uri);
RequestBody := 'scope=https://.sharepoint.com/.default&client_id=&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-
type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=<Your cliet assertion a long
string&grant_type=client_credentials';
Content.WriteFrom(RequestBody);
Content.GetHeaders(Headers);
Headers.Remove('Content-Type');
Headers.Add('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

```
    Client.Post(Uri, Content, ResponseMessage);
    Content := ResponseMessage.Content();
    Content.ReadAs(ResponseBody);
    if not ResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode() then begin
        AuthError := ResponseBody;
        exit;
    end;

    Json.ReadFrom(ResponseBody);
    AccessToken := GetTextValueForKeyInJson(Json, 'access_token');
end;
```

IN Postman
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxsQt.png)