How to make (non-compliant) GET request with XML body in .NET?
In Python and Postman I can make non-standard GET requests that include body with XML content.
answer = requests.get(url=url, auth=auth_handler, data=request_data, ...)


But I cannot make GET request in .NET using HttpClient:
   var content = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
   // I miss the XML content as parameter in GET command here
   var answer =  _Client.GetAsync(url /*missing data=requestData*/).Result;   
  //POST method is not allowed by the server here
   var answer2 = _Client.PostAsync(url, content).Result;  

Similar thread here but do not see any usable answer how to actually execute this non-standard query.
Any ideas?

Using this answer stackoverflow.com/a/47902348/2224701
it works:
var handler = new WinHttpHandler();
handler.ServerCredentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, userPassword);            
var client = new HttpClient(handler);
    var content = new StringContent(requestData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri(url),
    Content = content
};
var answer = client.SendAsync(request).Result;


AFAIK, you should be able to construct a RequestMessage with a Body and send that via SendAsync? (Not 100 % sure, though).

Maybe this will do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43421126/how-to-use-httpclient-to-send-content-in-body-of-get-request? Fwiw, id await your calls as well ..

Can anyone please explain to me how question about POST request solves this problem?

Well, in this answer you could change it to "GET"

Ok, it is duplicate, but the real answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902348/2224701
