# Suppressing verbs in Outbound Message in WCF-WebHttp Transport

Tags: rest, biztalk, msdn, biztalk-2013

I'm practicing the tutorial here - [Invoking REST Interface using BizTalk Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572836.aspx)

In that page, the step 3(e) indicates to provide GET as the verb to be suppressed in the outbound message for the property - `Suppress Body for Verbs`. The explanation given is not clear to me.

As an experiment, I removed the GET verb and dropped an input file. The application got suspended with the following error:

```
System.Net.ProtocolViolationException: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Server stack trace: 
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckProtocol(Boolean onRequestStream)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.GetOutputStreamAsyncResult..ctor(HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest, HttpOutput httpOutput, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.WebRequestHttpOutput.BeginGetOutputStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.SendWithoutChannelBindingToken()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult.Send()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpOutput.SendAsyncResult..ctor(HttpOutput httpOutput, HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage, Boolean suppressEntityBody, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.StartSend(Boolean completedSynchronously)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.Begin()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginCall(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object asyncState)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.BeginRequest(Message message, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendRequestMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage, IRequestChannel channel)
at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.SendMessage(IBaseMessage bizTalkMessage) 
MessageId:  {9FA7042A-0391-4AAF-946F-FE9C5516ABFD}
InstanceID: {4C29E43D-278A-4615-8A30-4ED1B1CBC2AD}
```

Why is this required and what exactly happens when I don't suppress it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default BizTalk sends a message payload (content-body) when it sends.

When you are trying to use a RESTful service and want to do a GET you usually don't want to send a message payload, you just too fetch the contents from a URL, hence you want to suppress sending a content-body.

See related question [Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type)

What will happen if you send a content-body with a GET request varies.
Some proxies might mangle or error on the request or the end server may throw and exception as it was not expecting a content-body.

Answer (score 1):

You need to supress the body, not the verb.  There's a custom pipeline component that's been built and availble here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/biztalk-2010-r2-rest-wcf-fdb2e91f to do this for you.