# How to redirect a request based on rules

Tags: c#, iis, akka.net

I have 3 servers AAA, BBB, CCC hosted web.api when API called from a client I want the process some special parameterized request into a specific server for example if the request contains parameter like AA then process into AAA, and BB then process into BBB and if DDD then process into any server based on round robin or least workload.

And return a response to the client.

How it possible to achieves through akka.net or C# using distributed computing?

Comment: What have you tried? How is the result the code you tried exhibiting different behavior from what you expect? Please see the [How To Ask A Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025566/best-way-to-have-one-web-api-forward-request-to-other

Comment: IIS ARR is possibly an option, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/planning-for-arr/using-the-application-request-routing-module while you can develop your own API gateway to distribute load as well.

Comment: @LexLi It possible with the help of akka.net ?

Comment: Like @LexLi mentioned, IIS ARR is a good option for reverse proxy/rewrite rules.  Take a look at .Net [DelegatingHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler(v=vs.118).aspx) as well.