# how to get image from url c#.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using HttpWebRequest to get stream from url.In .Net Framework,I get image stream like this:

```
HttpWebRequest rq=(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
Stream stream=rq.GetRequestStream();
```

This works perfect.When I do this in .Net Core,it does't works.the code like this:

```
HttpWebRequest rq=WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(url));
Stream stream=rq.GetRequestStreamAsync().Result;
```

How can I achieve this in ASP.NET core?

Comment: Please read [ask] and elaborate on "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you closing the request stream before making call to get response?

Comment: @CodeCaster,thanks for your advice.It's my first use of Stackoverflow.I'll do better next time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose you are getting `AggregateException` of `ProtocolViolationException`. (You may find the detailed explanation at [the other question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type).)

If you are trying to GET something from the remote URL, you should use [GetResponseAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync.aspx).

By the way, I suggest additional reading on [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt674882.aspx).

Comment: User is trying to call an async method synchronously which is not needed/not a good practice but GetRequestStreamAsync().Result should also work, although it will be a blocking call.

Comment: @SSA Thanks. I did some field tests and updated the answer.

Comment: @DanteisnotaGeek Thanks for your answer,I have tried to use GetResponseAsync  stead of GetRequestStreamAsync,and it works well now.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 using (HttpClient c = new HttpClient())
 {
      using (Stream s = await c.GetStreamAsync(imgUrl))
      {
          // do any logic with the image stream, save it,...
      }
 }
```