# Exception -"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type" using httpclient.sendasync

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

Already tried searching SO for similar issues but those didn't help to resolve.

## Scenario:

Have a Web Client app which has a Web API app as a backend. There is no issue when calling the same URI if it's from this Client - Web API but the exception happens when I'm trying to trigger the API request from another WebAPI Services application ( say its a separate project for accessing reports which run as a service using Telerik Reporting).

Code:

```
 private async Task<HttpStatusCode> AccessService()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            try
            {

                using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                {
                    Content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(JSONValues, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"),
                    RequestUri = new Uri(UriString),
                    Method = CallMethod
                })
                {

                   request.Headers.Authorization =  new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", Utils.Token) ;

                    response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        string httpResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                            httpString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(httpResponse);
                    }
                    ErrorCode = response.StatusCode;
                    response.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Misc.Error= ex.Message;
            }
            finally
            {
                response.Dispose();
            }

            return ErrorCode;

        }
```

Exception:

*Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.*

```
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckProtocol(Boolean onRequestStream)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetRequestStream(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.StartGettingRequestStream(RequestState state)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.PrepareAndStartContentUpload(RequestState state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

This works fine when I access the same from the Client app ( asp.net mvc ) and issue happens when I call this from the Report Services API app. Is this has something to with it.

Edit:

The Web client Project is asp.net mvc core 2.1, so I think it works while using content in GET method of HttpClient.SendAsync but the Reports Services App where this issue happens are targets .net 461 .

I strongly doubt this might be the cause since .net framework doesn't allow content for GET operations? Any work arounds?
[Link](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/28135)

TIA

Comment: When it fails what is the value of `CallMethod`?

Comment: @ToddMenier CallMethod is GET

Answer (score -1):

Based on the description provided, if you use get method you usually don't have a body in the get request. For more details, please refer to the solutions below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type

Comment: thanks but already checked that ... I already have a request body send