# Restsharp error "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

I am making a call to an eBay api using restsharp. The code follows.

```
    Async Sub fulfillmentPolicies()

        Dim request As New RestRequest(sFulfillmentURL, Method.Get)
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " & uT.access_token)
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        Try
            Dim response = Await client.GetAsync(request)
            If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
                Dim sR As String = response.Content
                Dim pP As PaymentPolicy = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Of PaymentPolicy)(sR)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
```

Client is set outside this procedure as it is used several times.

In testing when I make this call I get the error message "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type." I can make this call successfully in Postman using the same headers. Any thoughts on what is happening here? Ways to fix?

Comment: is that all your code? That error happens if you try to send parameters in the body, but you don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Oh, I see, it's the ContentType header

Comment: Are you saying I should not be using the ContentType header?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Content-Type` describes the format of the body in the REQUEST. It is not supposed to be used to tell the server what type of data to return.

The presence of the Content-Type header is causing an error in the .NET library as it tries to enforce the rule of not including a body with GET, and not including a header that implies a body is present.

You should be able to remove that header, but some APIs may not be compliant. It is better to sets `Accepts` to indicate you accept JSON as a response.

Comment: Such an easy fix! Thank you!!

Comment: this is very quite simple answer. Awsome. Thank you...