# laravel receiving GET instead of POST

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this route

```
 Route::post('exclusive-zone', 'SiteController@postExclusiveZone');
```

which gets a POST request from a redirected URL from another application in a different domain.(Think redirect of paypal after payment). But I get a

```
 MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
```

Trying to change it to

```
 Route::get('exclusive-zone', 'SiteController@postExclusiveZone');
```

returns a success, but of course, I cannot retrieved the POST-ed data.

I tried also working a plain PHP,

```
 <?php
 echo $_POST['data'];
 ?>
```

displays the 'data', so the redirect sends a POST. Can someone explain?

update:

tried

```
Route::any('exclusive-zone', 'SiteController@postExclusiveZone');
```

this is what I get with Log::info($request)

```
 [2015-09-08 13:43:52] local.INFO: GET /exclusive-zone HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: don't include any dash in your route name. I think that might be a problem, try changing your route name

Comment: @Sid anyway I can reroute them? since that URL is from another server that I do not have control.

Comment: you mean you can't change your route name?

Comment: yes. That 'route' was provided by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the redirect is sending post request but posting data with a GET request

[Sending POST data with GET request valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064281/sending-post-data-with-get-request-valid)

Comment: will $_POST still work if the servers POSTed the data via GET?

Comment: Couldn't give you an answer tbh? When you post to  get what does the request object contain?

Comment: Third party cant do a proper post?

When you say empty do you mean the Laravel request object is empty?

http://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request