# Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type for GET Calls

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, httpclient

I was using the extension method `ToHttpRequestMessage()` from `System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageExtensionMethods`

[Source code for MessageExtensionMethods](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Channels/System/ServiceModel/Channels/MessageExtensionMethods.cs,b2df92fe58a01387,references)

I created a `HttpRequestMessage` from `Message` using the extension method in the above link. Then i used this `HttpRequestMessage` to be sent via `HttpClient` but I got the following exception

> Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

[Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type)

Does that mean that I cannot use the extension method or do I have to do anything specific for `GET` calls such as not setting the content-body?

Comment: When you issue a `GET`, you **cannot have** a content body

Comment: Are there any other headers as well which i should make sure that they are not part of GET calls. Also just to make sure that this restriction is for GET calls only and not other HTTP verbs

Comment: `GET` is intended to **retrieve/fetch** data - therefore a content body doesn't make any sense. Same goes for `DELETE`. You use a content body when you want to **send in** data to the service - such as in `POST`, `PUT` or `PATCH` situation. You need to read an intro to what the HTTP verbs are and what they mean and what options / restrictions they might have

Comment: More on the methods here: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html

Comment: @RobertBräutigam can't see patch there. Is is incomplete / outdated?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh you're right, I linked to the old RFC. The new one is here: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3. Also the PATCH is in a different RFC here:  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789. There are potentially other Methods defined in other RFCs (WebDAV comes to mind). Anyway the GET method has no defined semantics for body content, servers *may* reject a GET request with content.

Comment: It's not forbidden to send content body on a GET request. And there are applications that use it, like ElasticSearch. This is just another example of MS trying to be helpful but screwing things up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064281/sending-post-data-with-get-request-valid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981564/cannot-send-a-content-body-with-this-verb-type)