# .Net passing JSON data to Rest GET method

Tags: .net, json, rest, wcf

I am aware that normally it should not be possible to send content through a GET request !
I am however working on a piece of software for a client where the existing (in production) web rest service of their application exposes the following method :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[JSONPBehaviorAttribute(callback = "callback")]       
CrmDataObject Connection(CrmDataObject crmData)
```

I think that the Method should be "POST", but is is GET and there is not much I can do about this at this stage since this code is in production and there are several third party softwares that are calling this function.

I, however, tried to write a simple client to call this method and keep failing for obvious reasons :

```
    var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.ContentType = "application/json";
    byte[] bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);

    req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

    using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
    {
       stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    }
```

I am getting "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type", logically.

How come are 3rd party apps able to call this method and pass a json parameter ? Is it possible to do it in .Net ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

`GET` specifically doesn't allow for a request body which is why you are getting `"Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type"`.

You typically pass GET parameters through the URL, generally in the query string (eg `"path/to/page?param1=value1&param2=value2"`). It's been a while since I did WCF, but I think this will actually work if the properties from your type (`CrmDataObject`) match the query string -- though I would have thought you'd have to have [`BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.webinvokeattribute.bodystyle?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_ServiceModel_Web_WebInvokeAttribute_BodyStyle).

If you have existing client code that works, ideally you could make a request while you have a debugger attached with a breakpoint at the beginning of this function, and then you could see the original request URL (in the `Request` object) as well as what was populated into `crmData`.

```
var req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url + "?name=value1&name2=value2");
```

Comment: Well, technically, GET requests can have bodies, but it appears .NET does not support generating GET requests with bodies. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064281/sending-post-data-with-get-request-valid I wonder how the 3rd party apps mentionned above manage call this method though... Since the service explicitely requests JSON, it's problably to happening through Query strings...

Comment: I don't have the source of the working client code unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

Depite the fact there's a lot of information needed to make a better suggestion I think your problem might be with the [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

¿Have you tried passing the parameters within the URL? like:

```
www.myurl.com/Connection?param1=hello&param2=world
```

Take in consideration that the name of each parameter in the URL must match a property in the CrmDataObject to be parsed by the model binder.

Comment: This would conflict with the fact that the webservice expects JSON would it not ?

Comment: The model binder works for every request type, you can send XML and use the model binder to parse it but you'll have to set ContentType=application/xml inside the request to make it work.  
If you already tried passing the parameters in the body with no success there's no other option.  Give it a try...